# How to set filter for custom template dropdown column in Kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-ui

I am using a template dropdown column in Kendo grid. Below is the column definition:

```
// Col definition
{
    title: "Kind",
    field: "kind"
    template: function (data) {
        return '<input kendo-drop-down-list k-data-text-field="\'name\'" k-data-value-field="\'id\'"  k-data-source="<Array in $scope>" data-bind="value:dataItem.kind" data-ng-model="dataItem.kind" />';
    }
}
```

How can I setup column filtering for this template column?

I know I can set filtering on columns if I define the dropdown values inline in the column definition itself like below and setting `filterable: true` in grid options:

```
{
    field: "kind",
    title: "Kind",
    values: [{
      value: "1",
      text: "Kind1"
    }, {
      value: "2",
      text: "Kind2"
    }, {
      value: "3",
      text: "Kind3"
    }]
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/saravanaj/kmsn2ond/2/

Is there any way I can setup filtering for custom template columns? Any filter events I can plug into?